# How to work on 2D slices of a 3D array initially scattered as 1D slices to MPI processes without firstly gathering all to root and scattering back?

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to make my numerical solver to scale across multiple nodes.

The object of interest is a `std::complex<double> * Psi = new std::complex<double> [N_r * N_thetas * N_phis]`.
`N_r` can be as high as 6000, `N_thetas` as high as 700 and `N_phis` as high as 1402.

If this gets too big, the memory of 1 MPI processes is not enough to hold it.

I thus need to NEVER have it all in 1 MPI process.

Due to the logic of the algorithm, I scatter 1-dimensional slices to MPI processes as follows.

For each MPI process, I calculate a vector of tuples `[(L1, M1), (L2, M2), ..., (LN, MN)]` , which represent the slices, i.e. for example `Psi[:, L1, M1]`, the MPI process will receive.

I then `MPI_Scatter` the `Psi`.

I perform the operations on these slices on each MPI process. These operations (called of the first type) are independent w.r.t. each other (i.e., two tuples (L1, M1) and (L2, M2) are not related).

I now need to perform a different type of operations. This new type needs 2D slices of Psi. I.e. `Psi[i, :, :]`, where `i` runs from `0` to `N_r - 1`. This is in contrast to the first type of operations, which needed 1D slices of `Psi`.

These new operations are all independent w.r.t. `i`. I want each MPI process to receive a given subset of `i` indices and to perform operations on those 2D slices it receives.

The problem is, how do I communicate between processes such that I get a re-distribution of `Psi`?
Psi is in a state in which it is scattered as 1D slices across all the MPI processes. I need a way to make each MPI process work on a set of 2D slices (`Psi[i, :, :]`).

I simply do not see a way to make this work without collecting all the `Psi` 1D slices from all MPI processes into the root process, and then to scatter.

Do you see any way to perform this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read about MPI derived datatypes. It looks like you need a strided subset of your data, which you can get with `MPI_Type_vector`.

Comment: Btw, why `new`? Use a `std::vector`. More convenient and essentially no overhead at your scale.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, w.r.t. ``std::vector``, yes, I have skimmed through all your books. I know the deal from your books. This is how I wrote it when I firstly started, then I didn't change it, as it works as it is. Thank you. I will read about ``MPI_Type_vector``

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, just to make sure I understand. Are you suggesting I create one such 
 ``MPI_Type_vector`` container inside each MPI process, after I perform the first type of operations, then ... ? I mention that I already scattered the 1D slices to each MPI process, based on the ``(L, M)`` indices each process needs.